# List all combinations between two lists where element of first list is smaller than the element of the second list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, combinations, permutation

I am using python 3 and itertools to create all possible combinations between two lists. However I need to add a constraint where the first element of each pair needs to be less than the second element.

For example:

```
list1=['A1','A2','C1']
list2=['A1','B1','B2']
result = list(itertools.product(list1, list2))
```

Returns

```
[("A1", "A1"), ("A1", "B1"), ("A1", "B2"), ("A2", "A1"), ("A2", "B1"), ("A2", "B2"), ("C1", "A1"), ("C1", "B1"), ("C1", "B2")]
```

At this point I would like to exclude all the elements where the first letter of list1 is greater than the first letter of list2. In this case the last three elements in result would be excluded because C is greater than A,B.

So the final result equals

```
[("A1", "A1"), ("A1", "B1"), ("A1", "B2"), ("A2", "A1"), ("A2", "B1"), ("A2", "B2")]
```

Comment: why not apply a filter after you make all the combinations?

Comment: `list((x,y) for x, y in itertools.product(list1, list2) if x[0] <= y[0])`?

Comment: Also you cannot have `("A1", "A1")`  in your result, since `A1 = A1` but you said first element in less than second element, or is your condition incorrect in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Why not filter out the elements after you generate them. Essentially, create the product iterator and only choose elements `(x,y)` where `x < y`

```
result = [(x,y) for x, y in itertools.product(list1, list2) if x < y]
```

The output will be

```
[('A1', 'B1'), ('A1', 'B2'), ('A2', 'B1'), ('A2', 'B2')]
```